# Geometric random variable and its expectation

Tags: probability, statistics

Let X be a geometric random variable with p = 1/2. Compute E(X^3). I got the value of 26 as my answer. Is my approach correct?

Firstly let's establish q = 1 - p for the sake of simplicity.

Secondly, I have already calculated that: $$E({X^2}) = {q+1\over p^2} , E({X}) =  {1\over p}$$

Thus:

$$E({X^3}) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty i^3q^{i-1}p = \sum_{i=1}^\infty ({i-1})^3q^{i-1}p + 3\sum_{i=1}^\infty ({i-1})^2q^{i-1}p + 3\sum_{i=1}^\infty ({i-1})q^{i-1}p + \sum_{i=1}^\infty q^{i-1}p$$
$$= \sum_{j=0}^\infty j^3q^{j}p + 3\sum_{j=0}^\infty j^2q^{j}p + 3\sum_{j=0}^\infty jq^{j}p + 1$$
$$= qE({X^3}) + 3qE({X^2}) + 3qE({X}) + 1$$

Rearranging these equations;

$$({1-q})E({X^3}) = 3qE({X^2}) + 3qE({X}) + 1$$

$${p}E({X^3}) = 3qE({X^2}) + 3qE({X}) + 1$$

$${p}E({X^3}) = {(3q)}{q+1\over p^2} + {(3q)}{1\over p} + 1$$

$$E({X^3}) = {{(3q)}{q+1\over p^2} + {(3q)}{1\over p} + 1\over p}$$

substitute $$p = {1\over 2} ,q = {1\over 2}$$

and we get $$E({X^3}) = 26$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes 26 is the correct answer, but you have made several typos with uppercase $P$ instead of lowercase $p$ near the end.

Usually we use generating functions to help with these kind of computation.  For example, the moment generating function of $X$ is
$$
M_X(t)=\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]=pe^t+pqe^{2t}+pq^2e^{3t}+\dots=\frac{pe^t}{1-q e^t}
$$
($t<\log(1/q)$ for convergence of the geometric series) and so
$$
\mathbb{E}[X^3]=\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}^3}{\mathrm{d}t^3}\right\rvert_{t=0}M_X(t)=\frac{q^2+4q+1}{p^3}.
$$

Comment: Yes apologies, the typos have been rectified. Thanks for the confirmation and the clarifications.